# Kolmogorov foward equation probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

An ice cream machine is either operation (state 1) or being repaired (state 2). Repairs take on average 6 hours and the ice cream machine breaks down once a day on average. This follows a time-homogeneous markov process where time is measured in days.

Question: Calculate the constant transition intensities

I cannot calculate the transition intensities from state 1 to state 2. For the transition intensity from state 2 to state 1 I have used the fact that E(T2) = 0.25 and since T2 follows an exponential (-h22) where T2 is the sjourn time in state 2 however how would i calculate h12 or h11.

Any help would much be appreciated.

Comment: I think "breaks down once a day on average" just means "the machine stays good on average 24 hours".  It's analogous to "repairs take on average 6 hours".

Answer (score 1):

The transition matrix of the embedded Markov chain is given by
$$
Q = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and the generator matrix by
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
\frac14 & -\frac14
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Hence the Kolmogorov forward equation $P'(t) = P(t)A$ are
\begin{align}
P'_{11}(t) &= - P_{11}(t) + \frac14 P_{12}(t)\tag1\\
P'_{21}(t) &= - P_{21}(t) + \frac14 P_{22}(t).
\end{align}
Setting $P_{12}(t) = 1-P_{11}(t)$, equation $(1)$ becomes
$$
P'_{11}(t) = -\frac54 P_{11}(t)+\frac14.
$$
This is a first order linear differential equation of the form
$$
y'(t) + p(t)y(t) = g(t),
$$
so we compute the integrating factor $\mu(t) = Ce^{\int p(t)\ \mathsf dt}$, that is,
$$
Ce^{\int \frac54\ \mathsf du} =  Ce^{\frac54t}
$$
to get
$$
\left[Ce^{\frac34t}P_{11}(t)\right]' = \frac C4e^{\frac54t}.
$$
Integrating both sides and solving for $P_{11}(t)$, we find that
$$
P_{11}(t) = Ce^{-\frac{5 }{4}t}+\frac{1}{5}.
$$
Since $P(0)=I$, we have $P_{11}(0)=1$ as an initial condition, and hence $C=\frac45$. So
$$
P_{11}(t) = \frac15\left(1 + 4e^{-\frac 54} \right).
$$
We can also find the transition probability matrix by computing the exponential of the generator matrix:
$$
P(t) = e^{At} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(At)^n}{n!} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac15\left(1 + 4 e^{-\frac{5 }{4}t}\right) & \frac45\left(1- e^{-\frac{5 }{4}t}\right) \\
 \frac{1}{5}\left(1-e^{-\frac{5 }{4}t}\right) & \frac{1}{5}\left(4 + e^{-\frac{5 }{4}t}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$